# Scanner GT-1500 Epson can't be found by xsane, simple-scan or iscan

Tags: debian, scanner, sane

Currently i am trying to get my Epson GT-1500 to work.
I am using Sparky Linux 5.0.4-amd64 which is based on debian stretch 9.

The scanner Epson GT-1500 is not supported by sane, therefore it was required to download the approriate Iscan-Driver from the Epson Website.
After the installation i did following manual steps:

/etc/sane.d/ddl.conf, modified:

```
epson to #epson
epson2 to #epson2
```

since /etc/sane.d/epkowa.conf was there!

then edited the epkowa.conf:

```
usb 0x04b8 0x0133
```

then i edited the /lib/udev/rules.d/60-libsane.rules:

```
ATTRS{idVendor}=="04b8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0133", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"
#  Epson GT-1500 | Epson GT-1500
```

after a reboot, still no success.
then i created /etc/udev/rules.d/99-epson-gt1500.rules

```
ACTION!="add", GOTO="epson_rules_end"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", GOTO="epson_pid_test"
SUBSYSTEM!="usb", GOTO="epson_rules_end"

LABEL="epson_pid_test"

 # Check for the gt-1500.

ATTRS{idVendor}=="04b8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0133", OWNER="root", GROUP="root", MODE="660"

LABEL="epson_rules_end"
```

reboot, no success.

in every step i executed scanimage -L:

This process took very long but printed out:

```
device `epkowa:usb:001:003' is a Epson (unknown model) flatbed scanner
```

but iscan, simple-scan and xsane either stop working (simple closes) or are giving the message "no scanner found"

Output of sane-find-scanner:

```
could not open USB device 0x045e/0x0719 at 004:004: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x045e/0x07b2 at 004:003: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x8087/0x0024 at 004:002: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0002 at 004:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x13b1/0x003b at 002:004: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
found USB scanner (vendor=0x04b8 [EPSON], product=0x0133 [EPSON Scanner]) at libusb:002:003
could not open USB device 0x8087/0x0024 at 002:002: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0002 at 002:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x2109/0x0812 at 003:002: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0003 at 003:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x1532/0x0046 at 001:003: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x2109/0x2812 at 001:002: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0002 at 001:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
  # Your USB scanner was (probably) detected. It may or may not be supported by
  # SANE. Try scanimage -L and read the backend's manpage.

  # Not checking for parallel port scanners.

  # Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports
  # can't be detected by this program.

  # You may want to run this program as root to find all devices. Once you
  # found the scanner devices, be sure to adjust access permissions as
  # necessary.
```

run everything with and without sudo.

and more info:

```
scanimage -x 100 -y 100 --format=tiff >image.tiff
scanimage: open of device epkowa:usb:001:003 failed: Access to resource has been denied
```

running this as sudo takes long, but no image will be scanned....

and something i noticed after a purge and reinstall of iscan:

```
Entpacken von iscan-network-nt (1.1.1-1) ... iscan-data (1.36.0-1) wird eingerichtet ... expr: Syntaxfehler tail: ungültige Anzahl von Zeilen: „/lib/udev/rules.d/60-libsane.rules“ iscan (2.30.1-1~usb0.1.ltdl7) wird eingerichtet ...
```

I am not sure if this error is maybe responsible for the non-working scaning. 
The content of the files are looking good however, at least i assume it.

Performing:
    sudo strace -o strace.out -f scanimage -T
gave me:

```
5199  access("/usr/lib/iscan/esdip", X_OK) = -1 ENOENT (Datei oder  Verzeichnis nicht gefunden)
5199  openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/bus/usb/001/003", O_RDWR) = 12
5199  ioctl(12, USBDEVFS_GETDRIVER, 0x7ffcebbc2220) = -1 ENODATA (Keine  Daten verfügbar)
5199  ioctl(12, USBDEVFS_CLAIMINTERFACE, 0x7ffcebbc237c) = 0
5199  ioctl(12, USBDEVFS_SUBMITURB, 0x7ffcebbc2230) = 0
5199  ioctl(12, USBDEVFS_REAPURBNDELAY, 0x7ffcebbc21f8) = 0
5199  ioctl(12, USBDEVFS_SUBMITURB, 0x7ffcebbc2230) = 0
5199  ioctl(12, USBDEVFS_REAPURBNDELAY, 0x7ffcebbc21f8) = 0
5199  ioctl(12, USBDEVFS_SUBMITURB, 0x7ffcebbc2230) = 0
5199  ioctl(12, USBDEVFS_REAPURBNDELAY, 0x7ffcebbc21f8) = -1 EAGAIN (Die Ressource ist zur Zeit nicht verfügbar)
5199  select(13, NULL, [12], NULL, {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=1000}) = 0 (Timeout)
```

and then the last line repeats in an endless loop.... any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying as root? The udev-rules gives permission only to root.root, so giving users (or the group scanner and attaching your user to this group) might be wise.

Comment: yes, i am trying this as also as root and it isn't working. If it would work as root, i'd try the next step assign groups and attach those user.

Comment: the group scanner has two users: my logon-user and the user sane. still i am at a point where i have to admit there's a missing link i don't know what to do else.

Comment: I've added trace infos. any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found the problem!
When i first downloaded the iscan driver it was the version:

```
iscan-bundle-1.0.0.x64.deb.tar.gz
```

but somehow i though there must be a newer version, several hours of searching up on the epson site made me find a file called:

```
iscan-gt-1500-bundle-1.0.1.x64.deb.tar.gz
```

after installing this with the bundled install.sh script without sudo, the scanner reacted just at the first try and i was able to scan a page with xsane.... even without restarting my system !!!
Now i set up the scanner group and i hope everything is fine now.

I got the (working) gt-1500-bundle right here:

http://support.epson.net/linux/en/iscan.php?model=gt-1500&version=1.0.1

finally, after adding my login user to the scanner group with

```
usermod -a -G scanner myusername
```

and a following reboot, i could scan without sudo rights.

Comment: Hi, everything worked for me except that I still have to use sudo. my /etc/group file has the line scanner:x:118:saned,adriano . I already rebooted more than once, but  to no avail. Any clues to what else might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install first the

```
 iscan-data_1.36.0-1_all.deb
```

next the

```
 iscan_2.30.1-1~usb0.1.ltdl7_amd64.deb
```

I dont know how to search and install in the distro you are using.

This debs used to be in the old epson download page, but now it seems to be only one, in this [page](http://support.epson.net/linux/en/iscan_c.html)

Comment: installin the data will give this:

Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von iscan-data_1.36.0-1_all.deb ...
Entpacken von iscan-data (1.36.0-1) über (1.36.0-1) ...
iscan-data (1.36.0-1) wird eingerichtet ...
expr: syntax error: missing argument after „-“
tail: ungültige Anzahl von Zeilen: „/lib/udev/rules.d/60-libsane.rules“
Trigger für udev (241-1) werden verarbeitet ...

Comment: Then you must search for these packages in your system .deb management tool, I dont use debian or the derivatives so I dont know how to look, check your documentation to see if theres is a repository with the requeired packages

Comment: also it seems it isnt used the right command, try to post it, besides there is somekind of conflict with the configuration of sane

Comment: I also get the error:

```
Setting up iscan-data (1.39.1-2) ...
expr: syntax error: missing argument after ‘-’
```

Comment: @TonyB were you able to get around the syntax error?

Comment: Not with the Version 1.0.0. See the answer. I used iscan-gt-1500-bundle-1.0.1.x64.deb.tar.gz as installer, than it worked like a charm. There's also a link